# Create an Arraylist of classes

Tags: java

I have an Arraylist  list1 (banana,orange...) , and i have a class fruit .
i want to creat an  Arraylist  list2 which its elements are instances of fruit and the names of instances are the elements of list1 . i did all intences with same name but i need a specific name fo each instance . is that possible in java ?
i tried this but it doesn't worked for me

```
public class list {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
       ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<Fruit> list2=new ArrayList<>();
       list1.add("banana");
       list1.add("Orange");
       list1.add("strawberry");
       for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
          String className=list1.get(i);
           Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
           Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
           list2.add((Fruit) obj);
       }
   }
}


public class Fruit {
    int price;
    String color;

    public Fruit() {
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `new Fruit()` to create your fruit? Do you have some constraints? Can you show us your `Fruit` class?

Comment: You should rather use a `Map<String, ? extends Fruit>` to hold your grocery data

Comment: Add a name to your fruit class as I've suggested in my answer.

Comment: `Class#forName` requires the full pathname of the class.

Comment: @GriffeyDog my package name is Malek ;i tried Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(Malek.className); but netbeans don't accept it ;suggestion :create classe Malek in package Malek

Comment: Do you *have* classes by those names?  All we know is that you have a `Fruit` class.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work correctly, all you need to do is include the package name before the class name.  Like this:

```
public class list {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
       ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<Fruit> list2=new ArrayList<>();
       String packageName = "some.package.name";
       list1.add("banana");
       list1.add("Orange");
       list1.add("strawberry");
       for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
          String className=list1.get(i);
           Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(packageName + "." + className);
           Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
           list2.add((Fruit) obj);
       }
   }
}
```

Java doesn't know what class you mean and it does not assume its the same package by default. You must explicitly tell it which packet.  (Unless it has no packet name, in which case the `packetName = ""`)

Comment: my packageNamee is Malek; i tried Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(Malek.className); but netbeans don't accept it ;suggestion :create classe Malek in package Malek

Comment: @Mikou: Don't use `Class.forName(Malek.className);`, use `Class.forName("Malek.className");` just like suggested in the answer above.

Comment: @Mikou: Is your class named `Banana` or `banana` ? Also, don't post screenshots of your error. Simply copy and paste them.

Comment: @jlordo there is no class banana; banana is the instance of the class fruit

Comment: @jlordo there are two classes in my code class list and class fruit banana is an instance of class fruit

Comment: @Mikou: If there is no class `banana`, you can't load the class `banana`. You can only have instances of existing classes. Seems to me, you should add an `String name` attribute to your `Fruit` class.

Comment: @jlordo thank you for your help , maybe i will use a hashmap <String,fruit> as saied William Morrison that's simpler getting data than use attribut name

Answer (score 0):

First, change this: `ArrayList<Fruit> list2=new ArrayList<>();` to this:

`ArrayList<? extends Fruit> list2=new ArrayList<? extends Fruit>();`

Then try this:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Fruit obj = (Fruit)clazz.newInstance();
list2.add(obj);
```

Comment: Why do you advice changing `<Fruit>` into `<? extends Fruit>`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Fruit> list2 = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
list2.add(new Bannana());
list2.add(new Orange());
list2.add(new Strawberry());
for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
   String className=list2.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName();
   list1.add(className);
}
```

Create the class, then retrieve the class name to populate the name array.

What I'd recommend more than this would be to create a fruit class which had getters and setters for names of fruit. Something like...

```
public class Fruit{
    private String name;
    //other stuff... nutrition maybe?
    public String getName(){return this.name;}
    public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
}
```

Associate a name with your fruit class.

Comment: wiliam my class have alrady an attribut name , but when i want to retrieve data, its more simple to write list2.get(indexof(orange)) than searching by attribut name

Comment: Ok, why not create a hashmap mapping fruit name to fruit? `HashMap<String, Fruit>`?